# php ip address redirect

Tags: php, linux, networking, redirect

I am having an php script, which changes the ip addres in the /etc/network/interfaces file.

After editing the file, I am using `exec("sudo ifdown eth0)` `exec(sudo ifup eth0)` to refresh the configuration.
It works but needs nearly 40 seconds.

I want to redirect the user to the new ip addres, by using:

```
header("Location: http://$ip/?page=networkSettings");
```

The redirection itself only works, if I comment out the exec calls. 
(Naturally I get "unable to connect error")

Otherwise the webbrowser shows:
waiting for 192.168.0.50

I used the php sleep function but it had no effect.

Does anbody know how to fix this?

Comment: `sleep` will make things worse, won't it? It seems like the browser is timing out waiting for the script to finish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to use some other method of issuing the redirect. Since the server's IP address changes while the script is running, this causes the connection to be broken — the Location header is never received by the client.

A method I've seen a lot of embedded devices use is a delayed redirect. Have your page display a result page that has a [meta refresh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh) to the new address, *then* change the machine's IP. Set the timeout on the refresh such that, by the time the timeout expires and the client redirects to the new IP, the machine should have its new IP up and working.

Comment: The result page should probably warn them not to try the new address too soon.

Answer (score 0):

Your `exec()` calls are missing quotes, causing a fatal error.

Answer (score 0):

Consider what you're doing: you take down the network interface, you bring it back up with a new IP, and THEN try to send a redirect to the client. But by that time, you're on a new IP, and the client is going to reject packets from that new IP because it's only expecting responses from the **old** IP.

Your sequence should be more like:

```
header("Location: $newip");
flush(); // try and send the header BEFORE you take down the network
exec('take down network');
exec('bring up network');
```

and even this might not be totally reliable, as PHP can only SUGGEST to the webserver that the output buffers should be flushed. You might actually do the network takedown before the flush finishes and then you're still in the same boat: redirect goes out on the new IP and gets rejected by the client.